# How to slide elements across the page on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I'm looking for some resources to create the implied, sliding functionality seen in the mock up below (never mind the half faded elements)
*Note: this isn't exactly what my code looks like yet, it's just the mock up.

[image]

I have been able to move the elements to the right only once with this function:

```
function slideRight(){
  var elem = document.getElementById('weekScroller');
  elem.style.left = (elem.style.left+290)+ 'px';
}
```

but this only changes the position once and I need the elements to continue to scroll each time I click the arrows. Also I'd like to make the scroll a smooth motion rather than a jump.

HTML:

```
<div id="weekScroller">
  <div class="weekScrollerDay">
    BOX 1
  </div>    
  <div class="weekScrollerDay" id="testID">
    BOX 2
  </div>    
  <div class="weekScrollerDay">
    BOX 3
  </div>        
  <div class="weekScrollerDay">
    BOX 4
  </div>    
  <div class="weekScrollerDay">
    BOX 5
  </div>    
</div>

<div id="scrollLeft" onclick="slideLeft()">
  Left
</div>
<div id="scrollRight" onclick="slideRight()">
  Right
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#scrollLeft{
  position: fixed;
  left: 35px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  color: #fff;
}
#scrollRight{
  position: fixed;
  right: 35px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  color: #fff;
}
#weekScroller{
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -200px;
  height: 400px;
  display: block;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.weekScrollerDay{
  opacity: 1;
  width: 280px;
  height: 390px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  float: left;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: consider it neccesary - always

Comment: We need the HTML to answer your first issue. As for a smooth scroll motion, you can use setTimeout() or setInterval() to increment your element in a direction every few ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a Jquery carousel called [Owl Carousel](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vObWmB) that i think would meet your needs. See demo  in the snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var carousel = $("#owl-demo");
  carousel.owlCarousel({
    navigation:true,
    navigationText: [
      "<i class='icon-chevron-left icon-white'><</i>",
      "<i class='icon-chevron-right icon-white'>></i>"
      ],
  });

  
});
```

```css
.owl-theme .owl-controls{
 margin-top: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}

/* Styling Next and Prev buttons */

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons div{
 color: #FFF;
 display: inline-block;
 zoom: 1;
 *display: inline;/*IE7 life-saver */
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 3px 10px;
 font-size: 12px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
 -moz-border-radius: 30px;
 border-radius: 30px;
 background: #869791;
 filter: Alpha(Opacity=50);/*IE7 fix*/
 opacity: 0.5;
}
/* Clickable class fix problem with hover on touch devices */
/* Use it for non-touch hover action */
.owl-theme .owl-controls.clickable .owl-buttons div:hover{
 filter: Alpha(Opacity=100);/*IE7 fix*/
 opacity: 1;
 text-decoration: none;
}

/* Styling Pagination*/

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page{
 display: inline-block;
 zoom: 1;
 *display: inline;/*IE7 life-saver */
}
.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page span{
 display: block;
 width: 12px;
 height: 12px;
 margin: 5px 7px;
 filter: Alpha(Opacity=50);/*IE7 fix*/
 opacity: 0.5;
 -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
 -moz-border-radius: 20px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 background: #869791;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page.active span,
.owl-theme .owl-controls.clickable .owl-page:hover span{
 filter: Alpha(Opacity=100);/*IE7 fix*/
 opacity: 1;
}

/* If PaginationNumbers is true */

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page span.owl-numbers{
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
 color: #FFF;
 padding: 2px 10px;
 font-size: 12px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
 -moz-border-radius: 30px;
 border-radius: 30px;
}

/* preloading images */
.owl-item.loading{
 min-height: 150px;
 background: url(AjaxLoader.gif) no-repeat center center
}

#owl-demo .owl-item > div img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom:4px;
}

#owl-demo .owl-item > div{
  background : #42bdc2;
  text-align: center;
  padding:10x 0px;
  margin:3px;
  color: white;
  font-size:32px;
  border:1px white;
}

.wrapper-with-margin{
  margin:0px 50px;
}

 
.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons div {
  position: absolute;
}
 
.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-prev{
  left: -45px;
  top: 55px; 
}
 
.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-next{
  right: -45px;
  top: 55px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper-with-margin">
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
     <div><img src="http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/bara2.jpg"></div>

     <div><img src="http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/volunteer2.jpg"></div>

     <div><img src="http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/volunteer1.jpg"></div>

     <div><img src="http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/choir.jpg"></div>

    <div><img src="http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/bara3.jpg"></div>
  
      <div><img src="http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/bara2.jpg"></div>

     <div><img src="http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/volunteer2.jpg"></div>

     <div><img src="http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/volunteer1.jpg"></div>

     <div><img src="http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/choir.jpg"></div>

    <div><img src="http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/bara3.jpg"></div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good solution that I may end up using, but **1** I'd like to build it from scratch (since I'm learning and this will be in my portfolio project) **2** I will be using Ajax to constantly update the data as I scroll. I think this version may give me problems since it is a loop

Comment: okay well there are plenty of solutions, you can study their javascript file and jquery methods tho

Comment: I down loaded the owl Carousel library and I see some great options. THANKS!